# Online resource for Marei Mekomos on the laws of Krias Shema

Tags: product-recommendation, internet, bircas-krias-shema

Does anyone know of an online resource for Marei Mekomos on Hilchos Krias Shema similar to this site: http://shaareihoraah.org/wordpress/?page_id=1046
Or even not similar.

Answer (score 3):

A few sources that come to mind:

- [Rambam on Hilchos Kri’as Shema](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Reading_the_Shema.1.1?lang=bi)
- [Shulchan Aruch on Hilchos Kri’as Shema](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x427)
- [Halachipedia](https://www.halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Kriyat_Shema)
- Our extensive [catalogue of Shema questions](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shema) right here on Mi Yodeya

Comment: You forgot https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shema

Comment: @Alex *sigh* Fine, fine.